# Javascript inserting into tags. And finding parent ID

Tags: javascript, parent, nodes

I have a script I'm trying to work on. I want to be able to find the parent id so that I can adjust the style background-color of it. I also want to insert a value into a certain "input" inside the parent div.

```
function changeBGC(color) {
    var testObj = this.parentNode;
    document.getElementById(testObj).style.backgroundColor = color;
}

function changeValue(value) {
    var changer = document.getElementById('DIVELEMENT?');
    changer.value = value;
}​
```

All this done with in Divs. I know I can define a specific id or class, but I have my website designed where all the DIV's are named the same. So I just want the script to work inside those certain Divs.

Can anyone please help. I can't seem to figure it out, and I mainly think it's just the parent.id I need.

Comment: *I have my website designed where all the DIV's are named the same.* ... Please explain...

Comment: Also, in `changeBGC()`, I think `document.getElementById(testObj)` should just be `testObj`, since `testObj` should be a DOM reference, not an ID.

Comment: So, in other words, `testObj.style.backgroundColor = color;` should work in that context.
`

Comment: Jared, when I try that, I get an error: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined. Which becomes an issue. I'm really new to Javascript and only doing this for a project. I applogise in advance.

Comment: Can you http://jsfiddle.net your markup and code? What you're giving us is not enough to understand the whole problem.

Comment: Okay. I have the `code`<script language="JavaScript">`code` in-between a Div tag. And I have a link that activates that script within that Div Tag as-well. I just want the script to change the parent div's style and child input value.

Comment: What's in that comment doesn't help. A live example is probably needed to fully explain what you're up to; please, http://jsfiddle.net an example.

Comment: @Bryanlgt0 So you have `<div><script>...</script><a>ClickMe</a></div>`?

Comment: It's very hard to explain. I just wanted the parent and child id's to be found. Here is somewhat sample I guess: http://jsfiddle.net/AdNLY/

Comment: This is one of those tasks that jQuery makes simpler, I believe. Try: http://jsfiddle.net/qpejk/ And see if does something like what you're trying to do.

Comment: Is everyone's answer always jquery? Sure it can make some things easier, I use it myself, but if someone doesn't know how to traverse the dom, then your doing them a disservice recommending jquery to them. Just saying...

Comment: I personally like Javascript more then Jquery, so when it's possible, I always try to do my research before I result to Jquery.

Comment: @Bryanlgt0 Is there a reason your fiddle code doesn't match your above code?